# Cannot compile: error: expected primary-expression before '(' token

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, compiler-errors, boost-multi-index

I cannot get this compile:

```
// main.cpp

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/indexed_by.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/tag.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;


struct by_attrs{};

// Generic MultiIndex that wraps boost::multi_index
template<typename Container>
class MultiIndex
{
public:

    typedef typename Container::template index<by_attrs>::type::iterator attr_iterator;


    template<typename FromArgs, typename ToArgs>
    std::pair<attr_iterator, attr_iterator>
    fetch_range(FromArgs&& from, ToArgs&& to)
    const
    {  
        return std::pair<attr_iterator, attr_iterator>(
                _container.get<by_attrs>().lower_bound(from),
                _container.get<by_attrs>().upper_bound(to)
        );
    }  

private:

    Container _container;
};


class Foo
{
public:
    int bar() const
    {  
        return 1; 
    }  
};


typedef multi_index_container<
    Foo,
    indexed_by<
        ordered_unique<
            tag<by_attrs>,
            composite_key<
                Foo,
                const_mem_fun<
                    Foo,
                    int,
                    &Foo::bar
                >
            >
        >
    >  
> FooMultiIndexContainer;


typedef MultiIndex<FooMultiIndexContainer> FooMultiIndex;


int main()
{
    FooMultiIndex foo_index;
}
```

Error (`g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp`):

`In member function 'std::pair<typename Container::index<by_attrs>::type::iterator, typename Container::index<by_attrs>::type::iterator> MultiIndex<Container>::fetch_range(FromArgs&&, ToArgs&&) const': main.cpp:28:55: error: expected primary-expression before '(' token 28 |         return std::pair<attr_iterator, attr_iterator>(`

Comment: It ain't gonna like `Container::template`. `template` is a keyword and cannot be used in conjunction with the scope resolution operator

Comment: @Bathsheba Apparently it's needed.  Joaquin's solved this.

Comment: Well, I am not officially obsolete. Have an upvote on the question - above my pay grade clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put a couple of `template`s here:

```
template<typename FromArgs, typename ToArgs>
std::pair<attr_iterator, attr_iterator>
fetch_range(FromArgs&& from, ToArgs&& to)
const
{  
    return std::pair<attr_iterator, attr_iterator>(
            _container.template get<by_attrs>().lower_bound(from),
            _container.template get<by_attrs>().upper_bound(to)
    );
}
```

You may want to consult this thread on the use of `typename` and `template` in so-called dependent contexts: [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: Sir, you are a genius, thank you!  And thank you for your contribution to boost.